# How to redirect after success fully registered in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I developed one page which is responsible for displaying cart items and the response is coming from backend upto this it's working fine .Now inside same page one more registration page is there and that also integrated with backend API, after successfully registered it should be redirected to /orderSuccess page but it's not redirecting ,Here what is the issue please help me How to fix this issue.

After registered it changes my url path /cart to /ordersuccess also but page is not displaying..please help me to fix this issue

`Cart.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="main">
    <div class="first-section">
        <div class="content">
            <h5>My Cart({{books.length}})</h5>
        </div>
        <div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" class="container">

            <div class="mid-section">
                <img v-bind:src="book.file" alt="not found">
                <p class="title-section">{{book.name}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="author-section">
                <p class="author-name">by {{book.author}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="price-section">
                <h6>Rs.{{book.price}}</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="icons">
                <i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>
                <input class="rectangle" value=1>
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-grps">
            <button class="btn" v-on:click="flip()" v-if="hide==true" type="submit">Place Order</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second -section">
        <div class="details-box">
            <input type="text" v-if="hide==true" class="initial-btn" placeholder="Customer Details" />
        </div>
        <div v-if="hide==false" class="fill-details">
            <form @submit.prevent="" class="address">
                <h4 class="heading">Customer Details</h4>
                <div class="name">
                    <input type="name" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,10}" v-model="name">
                    <label class="label">Name</label>
                </div>

                <div class="name">
                    <input type="text" required v-model="phoneNumber">
                    <label class="label">Phone Number</label>
                </div>
                <div class="pin">
                    <input type="text" required v-model="pincode">
                    <label class="label">PinCode</label>
                </div>
                <div class="pin">
                    <input type="text" required v-model="locality">
                    <label class="label">Locality</label>
                </div>
                <div class="address-block">
                    <input class="address" type="text" required v-model="address">
                    <label id="Add" class="label">Address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="city-landMark">
                    <input type="text" required v-model="city">
                    <label class="label">City/Town</label>
                </div>
                <div class="city-landMark">
                    <input type="text" required v-model="landmark">
                    <label class="label">LandMark</label>
                </div>
                <div class="Radio-Buttons">
                    <p>Type</p>
                    <div class="radio-btns flex-container">
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" id="Home" value="Home" name="type" v-model="type">
                            <div class="first-radio"> <label class="home" for="Home">Home</label></div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input class="work-round" type="radio" id="Work" value="Work" name="type" v-model="type">
                            <div class="second-radio"> <label for="Work" class="work-label">Work</label></div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input class="other-round" type="radio" id="Other" value="Other" name="type" v-model="type">
                            <div class="third-radio"><label for="Other">Other</label></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-continue">
                        <button type="submit" @click="handlesubmit();" class="continue">continue</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
export default {
    beforeMount() {
        // if (localStorage.getItem("reloaded")) {
        //     localStorage.removeItem("reloaded");
        // } else {
        //     localStorage.setItem("reloaded", "1");
        //     location.reload();
        // }
        service.userDisplayCart().then(response => {
            this.books = response.data;
        })
    },
    data() {
        return {
            flag: true,
            hide: true,
            booksCount: 0,
            name: '',
            phoneNumber: '',
            pincode: '',
            locality: '',
            city: '',
            address: '',
            landmark: '',
            type: '',
            books: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        flip() {
            this.hide = !this.hide;
        },
        Togglebtn() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        handlesubmit() {
            let userData = {
                name: this.name,
                phoneNumber: this.phoneNumber,
                pincode: this.pincode,
                locality: this.locality,
                city: this.city,
                address: this.address,
                landmark: this.landmark,
                type: this.type,
            }
            service.customerRegister(userData).then(response => {
                alert("user registered successfully");
                this.$router.push('/ordersuccess');
                return response;
            })

        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "@/styles/Cart.scss";
</style>
```

`router.js`

```
{
            path:'/dashboard',
            component:Dashboard,
            children:[{
                path:'/displaybooks',
                component:DisplayBooks
            },
          
            {
                path:'/sortLowtoHigh',
                component:sortBooksLowtoHigh
            },
            {
                path:'/sortHightoLow',
                component:sortBooksHightoLow
            },
            {
                path:'/cart',
                component:Cart
            }, 
            {
                path:'/ordersuccess',
                component:OrderPlace
            },         
        ]   
        }
```

Comment: Do you see any error on the console?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the history mode on your router settings. This should fix the issue

```
const routes = {
    path: 'Dashboard',
    ....
}

new VueRouter({routes, mode: 'history'});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/ordersuccess' })
```

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html